# Chain length with new derailleur

Tags: chain, derailleur

I bought a 8spd chain and am putting it on a 7spd bikes.  I thought I could use either a seven speed or eight speed chain. But it looks like the chain is way too long should I take out some links if so how many. The derailer I am using is from a different bike.

Paul[image]

Comment: The replacement chain is always too long.  Check the Park Tools website for an article explaining how to size the chain.

Comment: I had no idea.  I watched the video and was able to shorten it.  Thanks!